# How to add on delete cascade option in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I created two tables students and orders and I added a foreign key constraint to the order table but  I forgot to add on delete cascade option to this table.

table STUDENTS:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS (  
ID varchar(50)  NOT NULL,  
NAME VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,  
AGE INT NOT NULL,  
ADDRESS CHAR (25),  
PRIMARY KEY (ID)  
)
```

Table ORDERS

```
CREATE TABLE Orders  
(O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMAY KEY,  
Order_No int NOT NULL,ID varchar(50))
```

Add foreign key to "orders":

```
 ALTER TABLE Orders  
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders  
FOREIGN KEY(ID)  
REFERENCES STUDENTS (ID)
```

I tried this attempt :

```
ALTER TABLE Orders  
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders  
FOREIGN KEY(ID)  
REFERENCES STUDENTS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you delete rows from the `Orders` table that reference rows in `STUDENTS`?

Comment: I don't try but I want if I delete a row in Students table the same row with same ID will be deleted in Orders table

Comment: Yes, that's the point of `ON DELETE CASCADE`. But before asking and in case you haven't tried it already, try to delete a parent row in `STUDENTS` and see what happens (it should delete any referencing rows).

Comment: I didn't add records to the two tables, my problem is how to add ON DELETE CASCADE option to the Orders table.

Comment: I don't understand, have you tried issuing the last statement (with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option) and it failed?

Comment: Yes, i tried and it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the `Order` table. You have `PRIMAY` where it should be `PRIMARY`.

After correcting this, I tried creating the tables and all statements worked fine, including the last one.